# Not showing data fetched from api ( React Native )

Tags: api, react-native

I wanted to show a list of data fetched from API inside DropdownModal (https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown) . The data is user address consists of name , state , country and all related to address . But it won't show inside the dropdown and it shows loading icon which means it is null or undefined . But i did have the data fetched from the API which i verify by making alert to error and result ( yup both giving the same data which is the address ) .
Below are my code .

```
const {getAddresses} = auth;
var {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

class RegisterEventOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      event_id: '',
      tshirt_size: '',
      size: '',
      address: '',
      addressx: '',
     };
    this.onResult = this.onResult.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);

  }

  handleWithDropdownCategory = id => {
    this.setState({event_id: id});
  };

  handleWithDropdownSize = size => {
    this.setState({tshirt_size: size});
  };

  TShirtSize = size => {
    this.setState({size: size});
  };

  setAddress = address => {
    this.setState({addressx: address})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAddresses(this.props.event.id, this.onResult, this.onError);

  }

  onError(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));

  }

  onResult(result) {
    this.setState({
      address: result,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
            style={styles.scrollView}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.eventname}>{this.props.event.name}</Text>
              <ModalDropdown
                dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown}
                dropdownTextStyle={{fontSize:15}}
                style={styles.dropdown}
                onSelect={(index, value) => {
                  this.handleWithDropdownCategory(value);
                }}

                options={this.props.event.categories.map(function(event) {
                  return event.name;
                })}>
                <View style={styles.dropdowncontainer}>
                  <Text>{this.state.event_id === '' ? 'Select Category' : this.state.event_id}</Text>
                  <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
                </View>
              </ModalDropdown>
              <ModalDropdown
                dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown}
                dropdownTextStyle={{fontSize:15}}
                style={styles.dropdown}
                onSelect={(index, value) => {
                  this.handleWithDropdownSize(value);
                  this.TShirtSize(index+1);
                }}
                options={this.props.event.tshirts.map(function(event, index) {
                  return event.size;
                })}
                >
                <View style={styles.dropdowncontainer}>
              <Text>{this.state.tshirt_size === '' ? 'Select Tshirt Size' : this.state.tshirt_size}</Text>
                  <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
                </View>
              </ModalDropdown>
              <ModalDropdown
                dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown}
                style={styles.dropdown}
                dropdownTextStyle={{fontSize:15}}
                onSelect={(index, value) => {
                this.setAddress(value);
                }}

                options={this.state.address !== '' ? this.state.address.map(function(address, index)  {
                  return address.id;
                }):null}

                >

                <View style={styles.dropdowncontainer}>
              <Text>{this.state.addressx === '' ? 'Select Address' : this.state.addressx}</Text>
                  <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
                </View>
              </ModalDropdown>

              {/* <Text style={styles.header}>Compete with ohters (Optional)</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.header}
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                placeholder="Set Date & Time (Time zone)"
              /> */}
              {/* <View style={styles.checkboxcontainer}>
                <BouncyCheckbox
                  textColor="#000"
                  fillColor="orange"
                  fontFamily="JosefinSans-Regular"
                  text="Individual Competition"
                />
                <BouncyCheckbox
                  textColor="#000"
                  fillColor="orange"
                  fontFamily="JosefinSans-Regular"
                  text="Team Competition"
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.header}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  placeholder="Team member limit"
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.header}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  placeholder="Username / Email"
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.header}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  placeholder="Username / Email"
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.header}
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  placeholder="Username / Email"
                />
              </View> */}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.processIndicator}>
            <TouchableOpacity disabled>
              <Text style={styles.textProcessPrimary}>Previous</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Actions.RegisterEventThree({event_id: this.props.event.categories[0].event_id, category_id: this.state.event_id, size: this.state.size, address: this.state.addressx})}>
              <Text style={styles.textProcessPrimary}>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  {getAddresses},
)(RegisterEventOne);
```

The API :

```
    export function getAddresses(data, callback) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(value => {
    const token = JSON.parse(value);
    fetch('https:apiurl.com', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'bearer' + token.access_token,
      },

    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => callback(response.data))
    .catch(error => callback(false, null, error.json()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The loading indicator shows only if data(options) is `undefined` or `null`. Which means that you have no data at all, or data structure is bad.

You'v said that error alert is also triggered, which is not really a great thing. I don't know why the error is showing you some data tho. (except of error data).

Options should be passed in this format: `['data1', 'data2']`.

Also, your taking the data from redux => `this.props.event.categories` instead of state. If you want to use redux, then you are missing some kind of `mapStateToProps` in `connect` fnc.

There is a lot of wrong patterns in this code. take a look at some examples of how to use redux and also take a look at examples in react-native-modal-dropdown github repo if you want to use that.

Comment: Actually this code is not coded by me . It was coded by someone else in my team and he's not replying to my messages so you can say i dont really understand all the code but i have to complete atleast this before Monday . I also dont know why the error is giving me data . Both error and result giving me the same output which is the data . For the options , the tshirt size and category did show up in the dropdown but the address isn't . I will take a look at how to use redux to have better understanding . Thanks for suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

It's solved now . 
I just added ,true,null behind response.data .
It would look like this : 
.then(response => callback(response.data,true,null)